Splitting strings in pumping lemma for regular language
I was recently reading the book Introduction to the Theory of Computation, Second Edition by Michael Sipser, and encountered the following example:

Let $F=\{ww\ |\ w\in \{0, 1\}^*\}$. We show that $F$ is nonregular, using the pumping lemma.
Assume to the contrary that $F$ is regular. Let $p$ be the pumping length given by the pumping lemma. Let $s$ be the string $0^p10^p1$. Because $s$ is a member of $F$ and $s$ has length more than $p$, the pumping lemma guarantees that $s$ can be split into three pieces, $s = xyz$, satisfying the three conditions of the lemma.

The lemma contains the condition "$|xy|\leq p$", so I thought the string $s$ can be split into

$x=\epsilon, y=0^p,z=10^p1$

which does not satisfy the condition of the lemma, since $xy^2z$ ($0^{2p}10^p1$) is not in $F$. Also tried splitting the string into

$x=0^{p-n},y=0^n,z=10^p1$

where $n$ is an integer such that $0\leq n\leq p$. This also does not satisfy the lemma.
I would like to know where I am making a mistake.

Edit:
I was in a hurry and forgot the fact that one has to prove that $s$ is not in $F$. The following paragraph of the quoted paragraph above mentions that there cannot be a split that satisfies the condition of the lemma, thus proving that $F$ is non-regular.
For ones who are interested, this is the entire example given by Michael Sipser:

Let $F=\{ww\ |\ w\in \{0, 1\}^*\}$. We show that $F$ is nonregular, using the pumping lemma.
Assume to the contrary that $F$ is regular. Let $p$ be the pumping length given by the pumping lemma. Let $s$ be the string $0^p10^p1$. Because $s$ is a member of $F$ and $s$ has length more than $p$, the pumping lemma guarantees that $s$ can be split into three pieces, $s = xyz$, satisfying the three conditions of the lemma.
Condition 3 ($|xy|\leq p$) is once again crucial, because without it we could pump $s$ if we let $x$ and $z$ be the empty string. With condition 3 the proof follows because $y$ must consist only of 0s, so $xyyz\notin F$
Observe that we chose $s=0^p10^p1$ to be a string that exhibits the "essence" of the nonregularity of $F$, as opposed to, say, the string $0^p0^p$. Even though $0^p0^p$ is a member of $F$, it fails to demonstrate a contradiction because it can be pumped.


To prove the language $F$ is non-regular, the string $xy^2z$ is not supposed to be in $F$. This is how you draw the contradiction and conclude your proof.

Also, think of the pumping lemma as a two player game. Since you choose the string, the opponent splits it. So your argument should be based on a general split (the second case) and not on any particular fixed split (like in the first case).

@codeR I reread the paragraph and understood my mistake. It kinda flew over my head when I first read it. Thanks for the answer. I'll close the question later.

When using the pumping lemma to prove that a language is not regular, you cannot just find ONE decomposition $xyz$ that does not satisfy the three properties: you must prove that ANY decomposition does not satisfy the three properties.

So to speak, must one find a string that, no matter how it is decomposed, does not satisfy the three properties to prove nonregularity?

Yes, that's it.
